# Representing 5/(1+9x^2) as a power series and its coeffecients?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I have the equation f(x) 5/(1+9x^2) and to represent it as a power series I switch it to 5/(1-(-9x^2)) ---> 5∑(-9x^2)^n, my range of integration is correct but my first few coefficients of the power series I get are

C0: 5(-9x^2)^0 = 5(1) = 5  (this one is the only one I got correct)

C1: 5(-9x^2)^1 = 5(-9x^2) = -45x^2 -> -45

C2: -> 405

C3: -> -3645

C4: -> 32805

Am I making a stupid arithmatic mistake or is there a bigger problem and I just lucked out in getting the first one and range correct?

Comment: It stands to reason that, when they ask you for the coefficients of the power series, they are asking for the sequence $a_k$ such that the power series is $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^k$, not just for its non-zero terms.

Comment: They are asking for ak when k = 0 -> 4. I did a couple of other questions in a similar vein, ie. 6/(11+x) coefficients solved to 6/11, -6/121, 6/1331, -6/14641, 6/161051. 


I am trying that with the current series also.

Comment: What is the sequence of coefficients of the polynomial $17x + 42x^4$?